# EF union and count query

Tags: entity-framework

i have sql command below,how can i translate to ef query?

```
 SELECT SUM(T1) 
                               FROM
                               (
                               SELECT COUNT(*) T1 FROM PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT] t WHERE t.TXDATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-02'
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT COUNT(*) T1 FROM PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_ARCHIVE] t WHERE t.TXDATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-02'
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT COUNT(*) T1 FROM PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_CANCEL] t WHERE t.TXDATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-02'
                               ) M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) extension to combine your results.

```
    var startTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-01");
    var endTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-02");
    var products = context.Set<Products>()
                   .Where(p => p.TXDATE >= startTime and p.TXDATE <= endTime);
    var archivedProducts = context.Set<ProductArchive>()
                           .Where(p => p.TXDATE >= startTime and p.TXDATE <= endTime)
                           .Select(ap => new Products(){...});
    var canceledProducts = context.Set<ProductsCancled>()
                           .Where(p => p.TXDATE >= startTime and p.TXDATE <= endTime)
                            .Select(cp => new Products(){...});;

    var allProducts = products.Concat(archivedProducts)
                      .Concat(canceledProducts).ToList();
```

As you can see you will have to project each other product type to the same type. In this case we are projecting archived products and canceled products to a product entity.